# Mass Merge Move attachments back to previous account

Tags: merge

Mass Merge of account happened by mistake and we need to move all the attachments back to the original accounts.

I went into the recycle bin to undelete all merged accounts. Is there a way to look in the attachment history to reassign attachments back to original account?Or apex code or ApexExchange app that can help with this?

Comment: Messy. Do you have a full sandbox or weekly data export running? I don't think the act of reassigning an attachment is recorded anywhere... after all we can't update the `ParentId` after it was initially set, only SF internal code can do it... Do you have Chatter enabled? Maybe some old feed updates would contain info about attachments...

Comment: Has the act of merging updated the timestamp on the attachments? With that you'd at least know which records should be moved back... combine it with `Account.MasterRecordId` and there's some hope (still - good luck if 10 accounts were merged into 1).

Answer (score 1):

Account merges are *not reversible*. You're warned about this before performing the merge, in fact.

Since we're past that point, we can explore your options:

1. If you have a Weekly Export or Monthly Export, you can recover your data back to this last checkpoint by loading the records through the data loader.
2. If you have a Full Copy Sandbox, you can recover your data back to the last time you refreshed your Sandbox using the data loader.
3. If you have neither of these options, you can request a retrieval of the salesforce.com backup (warning: not for the faint of heart). I'd probably leave this one alone.
4. Try to repair the data manually by examining each document and uploading them to the right account.
5. Accept the fact that your data can't be easily restored, and start using the Weekly Export or Monthly Export feature.

Comment: I agree that #3 is "not for the faint of heart." They really don't want to be your backup solution.